# Remove maximized state in MFC windows application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

During create `MFC` application I have selected `Maximized` option in `User Interface Features`. Now I need start window in not maximized state, but I can't find in code where it is. Would you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your generated `CWinApp` or `CWinAppEx` derived class, search for this line:

```
pMainFrame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Then replace it with:

```
pMainFrame->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
```